# Can an answer be posted to a question closed as duplicate?

Tags: support, answers, specific-question, closed-questions, specific-answer

I am looking at this question: *[Processing lists of list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290809/processing-lists-of-list-in-python)*

It was closed as duplicate 7 mins ago.

But after closure there appeared two answers, 3 and 2 mins ago. How is that possible? I don't see "Post an answer" button and area to write my answer.

Comment: There's a grace period that allows anyone who was already in the process of writing an answer to go ahead and post it.

Comment: @KevinB thanks. I wish it can be stated in help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions. Right now it only says "While questions are on hold, they cannot be answered" which is not entirely true.